# Create a repository using Tower showing system files

Tags: git, version-control, git-tower

Everytime I create a repository using Tower it shows my system folder in the Working Files and not the folder I was after. When I try adding the folder it says "Existing Repository Detected" so I just click Add.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is how do I get Tower to just show the files in the folder I want to make into a repository and not all of the system files?